# checkboxes values not saving more then one

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, forms, checkbox

OK so i have a custom module setup and it is working great except on my admin form i cannot get the multiple checkboxes to save it always just saves the last one, i did locate other posts about this but not one of them explained a method to have a simple checkbox type with multiple values.

```
<?php
class JRG_Sro_Block_Adminhtml_Sro_Edit_Form extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form
{
protected function _prepareForm()
{

    $form = new Varien_Data_Form(array(
        'id' => 'edit_form',
        'action' => $this->getUrl(
            'jrg_sro_admin/sro/edit',
            array(
                '_current' => true,
                'continue' => 0,
            )
        ),
        'method' => 'post',
    ));
    $form->setUseContainer(true);
    $this->setForm($form);


    $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
        'general',
        array(
            'legend' => $this->__('Service Request Details')
        )
    );

    $sroDataSingleton = Mage::getSingleton(
        'jrg_sro/sro'
    );


    $this->_addFieldsToFieldset($fieldset, array(

        'sro_key' => array(
             'label' => $this->__('Service Code'),
             'input' => 'text',
             'required' => false,
             'readonly' => true,
        ),


        'phone' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Phone'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'order_id' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Order #'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'email_address' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Email'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'first_name' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('First Name'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'last_name' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Last Name'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'street_address' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('street'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'street_address_2' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('apt/suite'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
        ),

        'city' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('City'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'state' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('State'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'zip_code' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Zip Code'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),

        'warranty_services' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Warranty Services'),
            'input' => 'checkboxes',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Tighten loose stones '),
                        array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Adjust the prongs'),
                        array('value'=>'3','label'=>'Other Please Specify'),
                   ),
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'disabled' => false,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
        ),

        'additional_services' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Additional Services'),
            'input' => 'checkboxes',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => array(
                        array('value'=>'1','label'=>'test 1'),
                        array('value'=>'2','label'=>'test 2'),
                        array('value'=>'3','label'=>'test 3'),
                        array('value'=>'4','label'=>'test 4'),
                   ),
            'onclick' => "",
            'onchange' => "",
            'checked' => $data["additional_services"],
            'disabled' => false,
            'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
        ),


        'ring_size' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Ring Size To:'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
        ),


        /*'url_key' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('URL Key'),
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => false,
        ),*/

        'description' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Description'),
            'input' => 'textarea',
            'required' => true,
        ),
        'visibility' => array(
            'label' => $this->__('Status'),
            'input' => 'select',
            'required' => true,
            'options' => $sroDataSingleton->getAvailableVisibilies(),
        ),


    ));

    return $this;
}


protected function _addFieldsToFieldset(
    Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset $fieldset, $fields)
{
    $requestData = new Varien_Object($this->getRequest()
        ->getPost('sro'));

    foreach ($fields as $name => $_data) {
        if ($requestValue = $requestData->getData($name)) {
            $_data['value'] = $requestValue;
        }


        $_data['name'] = "sro[$name]";

        $_data['title'] = $_data['label'];


        if (!array_key_exists('value', $_data)) {
            $_data['value'] = $this->_getBarcode()->getData($name);
        }


        $fieldset->addField($name, $_data['input'], $_data);
    }

    return $this;
}


protected function _getBarcode()
{
    if (!$this->hasData('sro')) {

        $sro = Mage::registry('current_sro');


        if (!$sro instanceof
                JRG_Sro_Model_Sro) {
            $sro = Mage::getModel(
                'jrg_sro/sro'
            );
        }

        $this->setData('sro', $sro);
    }

    return $this->getData('sro');
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that the checkboxes allow multiple values.
You can do that by adding a name attribute like this:

```
 'warranty_services' => array(
        'label' => $this->__('Warranty Services'),
        'name'  => 'warranty_services[]', //add this one and make sure it contains []
        'input' => 'checkboxes',
        'required' => true,
        'values' => array(
                    array('value'=>'1','label'=>'Tighten loose stones '),
                    array('value'=>'2','label'=>'Adjust the prongs'),
                    array('value'=>'3','label'=>'Other Please Specify'),
               ),
        'onclick' => "",
        'onchange' => "",
        'disabled' => false,
        'after_element_html' => '<small>Comments</small>',
    ),
```

Comment: Not sure why but that is not working. Any Help Greatly appreciated.